# jsonp is not firing beforeSend?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am working on a project to call a webservice from different domain using $.ajax with dataType set to jsonp.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: testService.asmx,
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",

        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            alert('Before Send'); //Nothing happnes
        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert('Success'); //this was fired
        },
        complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
            alert('After Send'); //this was fired
        }
    });
```

The problem is I have a ...loading animation which I want to display while the web service request is being processed. I tried using "beforeSend:" to show the loading animation but it seems like "beforeSend" is not getting fired.

The animation works fine when the app is on the same domain (using jsonp) but when I move the app into a different server, everything works except "beforeSend" is not getting called. So users will not be able to see the loading animation.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross-domain JSONP requests do not use XMLHTTPRequest, so the event flow is different.

You can simply show your loading animation right after calling $.ajax.

Answer (score 0):

`beforeSend` implemention for jQuery JSONP is sill in progress.
The solution for now, use:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function(){alert('Before Send');}); // For all XHRs
$('#id').ajaxStart(function(){alert('Before Send');});         // For unique XHR
```

before `$.ajax({...});`.