# jQuery: How to enable `beforeSend` for `$.ajax({dataType:'jsonp'...`? Is there any solution?

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, jsonp

jQuery: How to enable `beforeSend` for `$.ajax({dataType:'jsonp'...`? Is there any solution?
http://jsfiddle.net/laukstein/2wcpU/

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:'http://lab.laukstein.com/ajax-seo/.json',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    async:false,
    beforeSend:function(data){ // Are not working with dataType:'jsonp'
      $('#content').html('Loading...');
    },
    success:function(data){
        $('#content').html(data.content);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just the nature of how JSONP works, creating a `<script>` tag, not actually using a `XMLHttpRequest` to get data.
For what you're doing, you can just run the code before, like this:

```
$('#content').html('Loading...');
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:'http://lab.laukstein.com/ajax-seo/.json',
  dataType:'jsonp',
  async:false,
  success:function(data){
    $('#content').html(data.content);
  }
});
```

Comment: Is is better and more correct to use `jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function(){$('#content').html('Loading...')})`?

Comment: @Binyamin - You *can* do that yes, it has a different purpose though, that runs *every* time an AJAX request batch starts, rather than when *this* one starts...if that's what you're after, certainly that's fine, and you can slim it down to `$('#content').ajaxStart(function() { $(this).html('Loading...'); });` :)

Answer (score 4):

As per jQuery documentation

> When data is retrieved from remote
>   servers (which is only possible using
>   the script or jsonp data types), the
>   operation is performed using a
>    tag rather than an
>   XMLHttpRequest object. In this case,
>   no XMLHttpRequest object is returned
>   from $.ajax(), and the XMLHttpRequest
>   object and the textStatus arguments
>   passed to the handler functions such
>   as beforeSend will be undefined. The
>   error callback will never be fired for
>   JSONP requests.

The same question is asked at the jQuery forums [`ajax:beforeSend for jsonp requests don't fire`](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajax-beforesend-for-jsonp-requests-don-t-fire)

The question's status is `Status : Working on it`. So it might be there at a future release.

And as Mike Alsups noted

> I would name than function something
>   other than 'beforeSend' since the
>   semantics are not the same.

Also related : [`jsonp is not firing beforeSend?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2774716/17447)

---

Cannot use beforeSend with jsonp. Period.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code:

befor $.ajax put it, and you should have an image(or div,span ,...) loading with "div_loading" id.

```
$("#div_loading").ajaxStart(function(){$(this).show();});
$("#div_loading").ajaxStop(function(){$(this).hide();});
```