# The ajaxSend event is not firing for ajax requests with datatype jsonp. How to make it fire?

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I am trying to debug all of the jquery requests on my page but for some reason the requests with datatype jsonp are not causing my global event to fire. I have no control over the ajax requests that are using the jsonp datatype so I need to come up with a solution that wont require changing the actual ajax request code. I can however make changes to the $.ajax function/jquery lib etc. I have a stripped down example that shows how it the event is not being triggered.

```
$('body').bind("ajaxSend",function() {
    alert('global ajaxSend');
});
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.example.com',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success : function(result) {alert('success');},
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown) {alert('error');}
});
```

In that example the ajaxSend event is not triggered. Does anyone know of a workaround or patch that will make it fire?

Comment: Really wasnt that hard to google... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663406/jquery-how-to-enable-beforesend-for-ajaxdatatypejsonp-is-there-a

Comment: I stated in my question ` I have no control over the ajax requests that are using the jsonp datatype so I need to come up with a solution that wont require changing the actual ajax request code.` so that does not answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jsonp request works by inserting a script tag in the DOM, so it won't fire the error handler, and probably not your global ajaxSend handler either.

Have'nt tried it, but you could always try triggering the event in the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.example.com',
    dataType: "jsonp"
}).done(function() {
    $('body').trigger('ajaxSend');
});
```

Comment: Probably want to trigger it in "beforeSend", not "success". And also pass the correct parameters - "jqXHR" and "settings"

Comment: I stated in my question that I cannot alter any of the ajax requests

Comment: @OmarJackman - Then you're screwed, and would probably have to use mutation stuff, like onDOMNodeInserted to check for new script tags etc.

Comment: @OmarJackman well what are you actually doing in the global "beforeSend"? Probably not calling "alert"

Comment: @Ian - was'nt sure it would work, as "beforeSend" is an ajax event that uses the XMLHttpRequest just like "ajaxSend", but according to the docs it should fake an XHR object anyway, so it probably will work that way to.

Comment: @adaneo I just meant that doing it in "success" would make it happen much later than it should (in case the OP is trying to set a header for the request or something). Im not sure what would work in this situation anyways, it was all theoretical from me :)

Comment: @Ian - I agree, "beforeSend" would be better, and according the documentation on $.ajax, it should work in theory, as jQuery will fake the parameters when a jsonp request is made, as that's not really a XMLHttpRequest, it's more just inserting an element (script tag), so it does'nt have the same parameters as the other datatypes etc. and that's why I was'nt sure it would work. Now it does'nt really matter as the OP can't do any of this anyway if he can't change the code for some strange reason?

Comment: @adeneo Haha yeah, who knows. And without any more information and what actually needs to be done, this is as good as its gets (other than the DOM mutation you mentioned)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and I solve it changing the bind to:

```
$( document ).ajaxSend(function() {
    alert('global ajaxSend');
});
```

As it is explaned here:

[api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/)

Comment: I thought this was gonna be tougher to fix
$(document).bind('ajaxSend', function ( ){ alert('global ajaxSend'); }) is alo valid BTW

Answer (score 0):

setting RegisterGlobalEvents to true can fire ajaxsend in case you dont see any other errors in console (add this right below ready function)

$(document).ready(function() {
var objGlobalEvent = new RegisterGlobalEvents(true, "");
...
..
//other form submit codes
});