# jQuery : Cross domain issues

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using **jsonp** and everything works perfect cross domain except some functions.. like:

```
beforeSend:function(){
     errobj.show();
    errobj.html('<b>Loading...<\/b>');
  },
```

it never shows loading if i am using it cross domain (subdomains).. also some animations and show and hide things never work.

Anyone has any idea about cross domain ajax/jquery issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, browsers tend to unilaterally block any calls being made to URLs outside the domain that served the current page. Use [JSONP](http://json-p.org/), which can request content cross-domain is the `<script>` tag. Check these links too
[Methods for Handling Cross-Domain Ajax Calls](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/ajax-cross-domain-142169)
[JQuery ajax cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

**[EDIT]**

Also there is an issue with `beforesend()` in `$(ajax)` for datatype `jsonp`. Cross-domain JSONP requests do not use XMLHTTPRequest, so the event flow is different.[beforesend() not firing in JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663406/jquery-how-to-enable-beforesend-for-ajaxdatatypejsonp-is-there-a)

Comment: if you read my question properly.. you would know what I am asking.. jsonp is already being used by me.. i am not asking how to get or send data.. i know very well how to use jsonp

Comment: @user1713941 sorry, i was just posting some resources which might have discussions on cross domain issue (since you suspect its a  cross domain ajax/jquery issues).

Comment: have you debugged it with firebug? any errors or warning. Also try putting some breakpoints also.

Comment: i think its the issue with `beforeSend` function. check this link [beforeSend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663406/jquery-how-to-enable-beforesend-for-ajaxdatatypejsonp-is-there-a)

Comment: yes @Nandakumar V your thinking is right.. i am going to remove beforesend and try plain thing.. will let you know once tested

Comment: given you +1 .. will accept your answer once tested.. thank you