# progress bar on beforeSend function

Tags: php, ajax

I'm having a problem regarding bootstrap progresso bar in my ajax beforeSend and complete, When i want to have a progresso bar i don't have success div response, if i take out it Works but it takes 3/4 seconds to show up. 
This is my code.

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: "nova_visitaBD.php",
                    data: {'iduser': iduser, 'local': local, 'data_partida': data_partida, 'hora_partida': hora_partida, 'data_chegada': data_chegada, 'hora_chegada': hora_chegada, 'turmas': turmas, 'disc': disc, 'docentes': docentes, 'obj': obj, 'tp': tp, 'custo': custo, 'alunos': alunos, 'iti': itinerario, 'obs': obs, delay: 2},
                    beforeSend: function (x) {
                        $('.progress-bar-warning').show();
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.progress-bar-warning').hide();
                        var result = data.status;
                        console.log(result);
                        if (result === 'success') {
                            $('#ajaxDivOk').html('Informação: ' + data.message);
                            $("#ajaxDivOk").fadeIn();
                            $("#ajaxDivOk").fadeOut(5000);
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#ajaxDivErro").html('Informação: ' + data.message);
                            $("#ajaxDivErro").fadeIn();
                            $("#ajaxDivErro").fadeOut(5000);
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                         $('.progress-bar-warning').hide();
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                  }
                });
```

This is my div

```
<div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="display:none"> 60% Completo (A enviar...aguarde)</div>
   </div>
```

The progress bar doesn't show up, why?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663406/jquery-how-to-enable-beforesend-for-ajaxdatatypejsonp-is-there-a

Comment: No....iv'e been searching for this yesterday all day and i don't see any valid solution. Thanks

Comment: Did you try ajaxStart/stop? https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Comment: my 5 cents: There's no reason to use `$('.progress-bar-warning').hide();` on both `success` and `complete`, just use it on `complete`

Comment: No, i have removed $('.progress-bar-warning').hide(); from success and i still don't have either progresso bar and  $('#ajaxDivOk').html

Comment: ajaxStart/Stop doesn't work either, in my console i have this error in this function: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                      } parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected number(…)